# Register additional beans from xml definition into application context that is already initialized

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I've got an application context  already initialized and I need to load another beans from xml definition into it in addition.

I can do applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()  but it is just for autowiring properties of some Object.

I can't find how to do that via XmlBeanDefinitionReader and ContextLoader, because as you can see, only public method is `loadContext(String... locations)` and it always creates a new context.

```
public final ConfigurableApplicationContext loadContext(String... locations) throws Exception {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Loading ApplicationContext for locations [" +
                StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(locations) + "].");
    }
    GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
    prepareContext(context);
    customizeBeanFactory(context.getDefaultListableBeanFactory());
    createBeanDefinitionReader(context).loadBeanDefinitions(locations);
    AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(context);
    customizeContext(context);
    context.refresh();
    context.registerShutdownHook();
    return context;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand that correctly, you want to load beans from xml locations to an already existing application context. You just go like this afaik :

```
  ApplicationContext context;

  BeanDefinitionReader beanDefReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context) ;
  beanDefReader.loadBeanDefinitions(locations);
  context.refresh();
```

Comment: doesnot do the component scan for me

Answer (score 5):

You have to "merge" your two ApplicationContext by setting your created context as child of the parent context and refresh the parent:

```
GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
context.setParent(parentContext);
parentContext.refresh();
```