# How to merge two ApplicationContext into one another in Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have two contexts in my spring java module

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "SpringBeans.xml");
```

and

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext helloContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("HelloBeans.xml");
```

with two different xml files. Now I have to get beans of HelloBeans.xml from `context` and beans of SpringBeans.xml from `helloContext` without refreshing the contexts.

Comment: Please take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973783/register-additional-beans-from-xml-definition-into-application-context-that-is-a

Comment: setting parent will allow only one way access, you can't access beans of child via parent

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't find what I was looking for, but this is the best I could do:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(
            context.getClassLoader());
Resource resource = pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
            .getResource("classpath:HelloBeans.xml");
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(
            registry);
xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Kindly share.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a parent spring context file (for example `AllBeans.xml`) and import `SpringBeans.xml` and `HelloBeans.xml`:

```
<import resource="classpath:SpringBeans.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:HelloBeans.xml" />
```

And the code would become:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext SuperContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("AllBeans.xml");
```

Comment: I have to use `context ` and `helloContext` only

Answer (score 1):

Trying below code, use "helloContext" finally:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringBeans.xml");
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext helloContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("HelloBeans.xml");

helloContext.setParent(context);
helloContext.setClassLoader(context.getClassLoader());
helloContext.refresh();
helloContext.registerShutdownHook();
```

Comment: It's OK on my test case, please show your code or configuration.

Comment: I have to get beans of HelloBeans.xml from `context` and beans of SpringBeans.xml from `helloContext` without refreshing the contexts.(both ways or in other words -vice versa)