# How can I register beans from Spring XML file at runtime?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to register additional beans from a file with the Spring context at runtime. I followed an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580811/) with this code:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private void loadBeans(String beansXml) {
    GenericApplicationContext createdContext =
            new GenericApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(createdContext);
    reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new InputSource(new StringReader(beansXml)));
    createdContext.refresh();
}
```

The passed XML string is actually processed by Spring, what I have verified by putting in an unresolveable reference about which Spring complained. However, when I trie to get a certain bean with

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

public void test() {
    context.getBean("myId");
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myId' available
```

Spring version: 4.3

What is missing or wrong?

Comment: Vote to close this question as "off-top because of: This question does not appear to be about programming ..." is ridiculous.

Comment: It's certainly about Spring, which is about programming.  I don't agree with the solution the OP is attempting, but the close for not about programming is unjust, in my opinion.

Comment: Do these context files have some sort of parent-child relation ship? If so this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837078/2160152

Comment: @cheffe At least I have not introduced any kind of parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comment of [cheffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2160152/cheffe) where he links to [another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837078/2160152), I've came to the following solution:

```
@Autowired
GenericApplicationContext context;

private void loadBeans(String beansXml) {
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context);
    xmlReader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD);
    xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new InputSource(new StringReader(beansXml)));
}
```

The problem seems to be the creation of the new `GenericApplicationContext`. It looks like the beans are only in this context but not known in the existing context.

Comment: I have property placeholders ( ${stuff} ) in my beansXml. LoadDefinitions(...) fails in this case with java.text.ParseException: Unexpected character: $. How to load beans from xml with property placeholders?